# gulp-imagemin not accepting options

Tags: gulp, gulp-imagemin

Since updating to version 3 of gulp-imagemin, I'm having difficulty pushing options through when running the task.
I can see in the documentation that the syntax for the options has changed, but I'm having no luck with the new syntax as described.

Here's what I have working in v2.4.0:

```
.pipe($.imagemin({
    progressive: true,
    interlaced: true,
    svgoPlugins: [
        {cleanupIDs: false}
    ,   {removeUnknownsAndDefaults: false}
    ]
}))
```

I've upgraded to version 3 and as per the instructions in the [release notes](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin/releases/tag/v3.0.0), I've changed the syntax to the following:

```
.pipe($.imagemin([
    imagemin.gifsicle({interlaced: true}),
    imagemin.mozjpeg({progressive: true}),
    imagemin.svgo({plugins: [
            {cleanupIDs: false}
        ,   {removeUnknownsAndDefaults: false}
    ]})
]))
```

However, when running the task this throws an error:

> Reference error: imagemin is not defined

I'm fairly new to gulp and the like, so there may be something fairly obvious I'm missing, but I've experimented with lots of subtle changes to the syntax, all to no avail. Can anyone help?

Comment: `$.imagemin` instead of `imagemin`.

Comment: I've tried that, but got the same result unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Define imagemin first.
const imagemin = require(‘gulp-imagemin’);
Then use imagemin instead of $.imagemin.